# Гренки - причина ошибки

Tags: орфоэпия

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какова изначальная причина появления "неправильных" грЕнок? Почему в слове стали неправильно ставить ударение? Есть ли какая конкретная причина этому? Я слышала версию, что причиной могло быть отсутствие в печатном тексте буквы Ё, но не нашла нигде авторитетного подтверждения. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: "Грязные руки - причина болезни".

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке ударение подвижное. Т.е. ударение может смещаться и от формы к форме и даже внутри формы в историческом разрезе. Если это сойдёт за причину, то ловите.

Но в нашем случае произошло ещё одно изменение. Историческое "гренОк" (в именительном падеже) - слово мужского рода, стало произноситься как "грЕнка", т.е. приобрело форму женского рода. Множественное число в подобных словах продуктивно образуется без смещения ударения. Гренок - гренкИ, грЕнка - грЕнки. Последняя форма признаётся современными словарями как допустимая или даже нормативная наряду со старой.

Буква Ё тут абсолютно ни при чем.

Comment: Это все ясно мне, спасибо. Мне необходимо узнать, ПОЧЕМУ норма (ведь было же правильный вариант) показалась "неудобной" русскому человеку и ошибка стала НАСТОЛЬКО популярной, что сейчас даже признается как допустимый вариант. А то, что ударение смещается, - так это мы вообще можем где попало начать его ставить, но ведь не делаем этого. Почему именно несчастные "гренки"? И чем изначальный мужской род не угодил, что в нем неестественного? Вот почему "какао" стал когда-то среднего ведь очень логично можно объяснить, Вы согласны?

Comment: Не согласен. 
Ни про кофе, ни с вашими рассуждениями насчет ошибки, которую повторяет большинство. Даже если 99 прОцентов дОцентов лОжат доКументы в пОртфели норсой это не станет. Нормой может стать только закономерное, отражающее общую языковую тенденцию изменение. Окказиональности тут - редчайший случай, в основном они авторитарны.

Comment: По поводу кофе и какао. А с чего вы взяли что ваше объяснение ответит на вопрос "почему?" Не "почему возможно?", а "почему произошло?" Разница, как понимаете, огромна. И вы настиваете именно на ответе на последний вопрос. Я ответа не него не знаю. Как, думаю, и никто не знает.

Comment: А гренок "не угодил" именно тем, что он был мужского рода, а язык счел, что ему надо быть женского. Как и с кофе-какао.

Comment: Я поддерживаю Ваше неодобрение таких изменений, но говоря, что стали признавать вторую норму, я ориентируюсь на специализированные словари, сейчас уже появилось достаточно много словарей, которые признают этот вариант допустимым. Думаю, рано или поздно это приведет к тому, что этот вариант вообще вытеснит изначальный. Не буду спорить насчет "кофе" и "какао", пусть будет "возможно" или "вероятно". Чтобы конкретизировать свой вопрос, ниже я приведу кусочек теста, помогите, пожалуйста, выбрать правильный ответ, если можете:

Comment: 3.Укажите,с чем связана ошибка в постановке ударений в следующих словах:гренкИ-грЕнки...?
 а)Ошибка с незнанием ударения,присущего тому языку,из которого данное слово заимствовано;
 б)Ошибка,связанная с отсутствием в печатном тексте буквы"Ё";
 в)Ошибка в слоге;
 г)Ошибка в написании

К составлению теста и формулировкам я не имею никакого отношения, его предложили моей знакомой, которая должна "досдать" русский язык при переводе в другой ВУЗ.

Answer (score 0):

Нормой признается, потому что большинство людей начали неправильно произносить. Пример тому наши учителя в школе: сами учат, сами допускают ошибки... Неграмотные люди порождают себе подобных)

Comment: Согласна с Вами, как только "вариант с ошибкой" в связи с частотностью попадает в справочники и словари, можно сказать, что процесс его "легитимизации" пошел :)